# Finding number of rooms in castle

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

If you have a given castle, and information below:

4

7

11 6 11 6 3 10 6

7 9 6 13 5 15 5

1 10 12 7 13 7 5

13 11 10 8 10 12 13

[image]

The first two lines are two integers, which are the amount of cells north-south and east-west directions in the castle. In the next input lines, each cell is described by a number (0 ≤ p ≤ 50). Use a number to indicate the wall around the square, 1 for the western wall, 2 for the north wall, 4 for the east wall, and 8 for the south wall. Each square is represented by the sum of the numbers representing the surrounding wall. The inner wall of the castle is counted twice, and the south wall of the square (1, 1) is also the north wall of the square (2, 1).

It works just fine on the given castle, but if I make some other castle design it doesn't work anymore, it gives bad number of rooms. Do you see the problem here?
I should implement this in c# language. So far that's how my code looks like.

```
private void CheckRoom(int i, int j)
    {
        if((i<0 | i>pilis.m) | (j<0 | j > pilis.n))
        {
            return;
        }
        // If room was visited, we return
        if (pilis.ImtiKambarioLankomuma(i,j) == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        pilis.DetiKambarioLankomuma(i, j, true);
        if ((pilis.ImtiKambari(i,j) & 1) == 0) CheckRoom(i, j - 1);
        if ((pilis.ImtiKambari(i,j) & 2) == 0) CheckRoom(i - 1, j);
        if ((pilis.ImtiKambari(i,j) & 4) == 0) CheckRoom(i, j + 1);
        if ((pilis.ImtiKambari(i,j) & 8) == 0) CheckRoom(i + 1, j);
    }

    private void CountRooms(Pilis pilis)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= pilis.m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= pilis.n; j++)
            {
                if (pilis.ImtiKambarioLankomuma(i,j) == false) //Indicates a new room that has not been entered 
                {
                    //adds +1 to total room count
                    pilis.DidintiKambariuSuma();
                    CheckRoom(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loops have wrong upper limits. Should be `<` instead of `<=`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= pilis.m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= pilis.n; j++)
```

Also

```
if((i<0 | i>=pilis.m) | (j<0 | j >= pilis.n))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looked like a fun problem so I decided to take a stab at it.

Output:

```
Castle Data:
4
7
11 6 11 6 3 10 6
7 9 6 13 5 15 5
1 10 12 7 13 7 5
13 11 10 8 10 12 13

Castle:
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|     |     |        |
+--+  +--+  +  +--+  +
|  |     |  |  |  |  |
+  +--+  +--+  +--+  +
|        |  |  |  |  |
+  +--+--+  +--+  +  +
|  |              |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

Searching for rooms...
New room found at row 0, col 0.
New room found at row 0, col 2.
New room found at row 0, col 4.
New room found at row 1, col 5.
New room found at row 2, col 3.

Total rooms: 5

Press any key to quit...
```

Code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data =
            "4" + Environment.NewLine +
            "7" + Environment.NewLine +
            "11 6 11 6 3 10 6" + Environment.NewLine +
            "7 9 6 13 5 15 5" + Environment.NewLine +
            "1 10 12 7 13 7 5" + Environment.NewLine +
            "13 11 10 8 10 12 13" + Environment.NewLine;

        string[] dataFromFile = data.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine("Castle Data:");
        foreach(string row in dataFromFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        CastleRoom[,] castle = CastleFromData(dataFromFile);
        if (castle != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Castle:");
            DisplayCastle(castle);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Searching for rooms...");
            int roomCount = 0;
            for(int row=0; row<castle.GetLength(0);row++)
            {
                for(int col=0; col<castle.GetLength(1); col++)
                {
                    if (!castle[row, col].Visited)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("New room found at row " + row + ", col " + col + ".");
                        roomCount++;
                        VisitRoomAt(castle, row, col);
                    }
                }                    
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Total rooms: " + roomCount);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void VisitRoomAt(CastleRoom[,] castle, int row, int col)
    {
        if (castle!=null && row>=0 && row<=castle.GetUpperBound(0) && col>=0 && col<=castle.GetUpperBound(1))
        {
            CastleRoom room = castle[row, col];
            if (room!=null && !room.Visited)
            {
                room.Visited = true;
                if (!room.HasWestWall) { VisitRoomAt(castle, row, col-1); }
                if (!room.HasNorthWall) { VisitRoomAt(castle, row-1, col); }
                if (!room.HasEastWall) { VisitRoomAt(castle, row, col + 1); }
                if (!room.HasSouthWall) { VisitRoomAt(castle, row + 1, col); }
            }                
        }
    }

    static void DisplayCastle(CastleRoom[,] castle)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < castle.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < castle.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write("+" + (castle[row, col].HasNorthWall ? "--" : "  "));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("+");
            for (int col = 0; col < castle.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write((castle[row, col].HasWestWall ? "|" : " ") + "  ");
                if (col == (castle.GetLength(1) - 1) && castle[row, col].HasEastWall)
                {
                    Console.Write("|");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (row == (castle.GetLength(0)-1))
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < castle.GetLength(1); col++)
                {
                    Console.Write("+" + (castle[row, col].HasSouthWall ? "--" : "  "));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("+");
            }
        }
    }

    static CastleRoom[,] CastleFromData(string[] castleData)
    {
        int rows, columns;
        if (!int.TryParse(castleData[0], out rows) || !int.TryParse(castleData[1], out columns))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (castleData.Length != (rows + 2))
        {
            return null;
        }

        CastleRoom[,] castle = new CastleRoom[rows, columns];
        for (int row = 2; row < castleData.Length; row++)
        {
            string[] rowData = castleData[row].Split();
            if (rowData.Length != columns)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int roomValue;
            for (int col = 0; col < rowData.Length; col++)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(rowData[col], out roomValue))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if (roomValue < 0 || roomValue > 50)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                castle[(row - 2), col] = new CastleRoom(roomValue);
            }
        }
        return castle;
    }

}

class CastleRoom
{

    [Flags] public enum CastleWalls
    {
        West = 1,
        North = 2,
        East = 4,
        South = 8
    }

    private CastleWalls _walls;

    public bool Visited = false;

    public CastleRoom(int walls)
    {
        _walls = (CastleWalls)walls;
    }

    public bool HasWestWall
    {
        get
        {
            return _walls.HasFlag(CastleWalls.West);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNorthWall
    {
        get
        {
            return _walls.HasFlag(CastleWalls.North);
        }
    }

    public bool HasEastWall
    {
        get
        {
            return _walls.HasFlag(CastleWalls.East);
        }
    }

    public bool HasSouthWall
    {
        get
        {
            return _walls.HasFlag(CastleWalls.South);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ((int)_walls).ToString();
    }

}
```